# Отладка с использованием Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, sqldeveloper

В существующем пакете я создал новую процедуру, скомпилировал ее успешно, но отладить ее не могу(она не отображается в окне для отладки). Как настроить SQL Developer?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы твоя процедура появилась в окне отладки вынеси её прототип в спецификацию пакета.

Comment: Прототип в спецификации есть, компилю как Compile for Debug, но все равно не появляется.